# Select one cell when pandas DataFrame has hierarchical index

Tags: python, pandas

I would expect to be able to do

`dat.loc['label_row1', 'label_row2', 'label_col']`

However, it does not work and require

`dat.loc['label_row1', 'label_row2'].loc['label_col']`

To me, this is rather unintuitive, because when there isn't hierarchical index, I can select one cell with

`dat.loc['label_row', 'label_col']`

Can anyone explain the reasoning or suggest a way to remember this quirk?

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import wb

dat = wb.download(
    indicator=['BX.KLT.DINV.WD.GD.ZS'],
    country='CN', start=2005, end=2011)
dat.loc["China", "2003"].loc["BX.KLT.DINV.WD.GD.ZS"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your index is first sorted, you can do this which selects all countries and the year 2009:

```
dat.sort_index().loc[(slice(None), '2009'), :]
              BX.KLT.DINV.WD.GD.ZS
country year                      
China   2009              2.590357
```

Here is a link to [indexing with hierarchical data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index) in the docs.

Because your index is a MultiIndex is a tuple, your .loc indexing needs to be a tuple as well.  Note the difference between the two methods below. One returns a series, the other a dataframe:

```
>>> dat.sort_index().loc[('China', '2009'), :]
BX.KLT.DINV.WD.GD.ZS    2.590357
Name: (China, 2009), dtype: float64

>>> dat.sort_index().loc[[('China', '2009')], :]
              BX.KLT.DINV.WD.GD.ZS
country year                      
China   2009              2.590357
```

Comment: I see. It seems that to do something similar to `.loc[row_label, col_label]`, my `row_label` has to be a tuple, because the hierarchical row index is a tuple. Is that understanding correct?

Comment: The doc does have a warning regarding sorting `Warning: You will need to make sure that the selection axes are fully lexsorted! `. Do you know why this is necessary? It's strange because this doesn't seem necessary when multi-index is not used.

Comment: I got an error when it was the original raw data which had the years sorted in reverse.  This link is to old docs, but explains why it needs to be lex sorted. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.7.0/indexing.html#the-need-for-sortedness